# Numpy arrays: can I multiply only a few elements in the array and not all of them?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using Python3 and numpy with matplotlib on a project to get Jupiter's Mass from observational telescope astrometry. I want to take an array of numbers, say from 1 to 10, and multiply only a few of them in order, say 1 to 4, by -1.

So 1 to 4 is now negative and 5 to 10 is still positive. I imagine out put like this:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array_L = np.array(L)
>>>array_L
array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
neg = array_L[0:4]
>>>neg
array([1,2,3,4])
Neg = neg * -1
>>>Neg
array([-1,-2,-3,-4])
```

Now I need a way of combining `neg` and `array_L` into a new final array that would output like this:

```
# pseudo code: Neg + array_L(minus elements 0 to 4) = New_L

New_L = array([-1,-2,-3,-4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Also I know it may be possible to do a limited element iteration over just the elements I want and not the whole array. I can do some of these operations on the list vs the array if it would make it easier.

Answer (score 4):

Just like with regular python lists, you can do operations on slices of NumPy arrays to change them in-place:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> array_L = numpy.array(L)
>>> array_L
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
>>> array_L[0:4] *= -1
>>> array_L
array([-1, -2, -3, -4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: Frikin sweet!  Never thought of simply phrasing the syntax that way.  Narf!

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there!  Try this:

```
L = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) 
L[0:4] *= -1
print(L)
```